# How i can fix error Invalid backend model specified

Tags: magento-1.8, error

when i try run magento, i see in log file next error:

> a:5:{i:0;s:74:"Invalid backend model specified:
>   eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_updated";i:1;s:6088:"#0
>   \app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Abstract.php(346):
>   Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid backend...')

Can you help how i can fix this? because i can not found solution((
any solutions please, Thanks

Backend working good, not working only frontend

Comment: Have you installed / removed any extension?  Have you added any custom attributes?

Comment: no, just moved site with hosting in localserver

Comment: Oddly enough, clearing my cookies fixed this error for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the table `eav_attribute` find rows with the field **backend_model** equal to given model and temporary remove them or change the model to the name of the existing class.

Comment: i found column backend_model and then row with eav/entity_attribute_backend_time_updated -  i remove eav/entity_attribute_backend and error is same, what i do wrong?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache? What was the attribute code?

Comment: No, i just fix in ext for Related tab core and problem is fix, very thanks Amasty

Comment: Glad to be of service :)

Comment: @Amasty can you please look on this thread and if possible give solution ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180657/magento-2-how-to-override-api-interface-method-in-our-custom-module