# create new orders does not work in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, xampp

I use Magento 1.7 , when i click to "create new orders", it shows error [see image below- Error 1]. Also when i click "view" to see my old orders which are pending it shows different error. [see image below- Error 2]

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the table eav_attributes find rows with the field backend_model equal to given model and temporary remove them or change the model to the name of the existing class.

for reference : [invalid backend model specified](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32678/how-i-can-fix-error-invalid-backend-model-specified)

Comment: Can you help me in detail. I am new to Magento. Can you tell me what is existing class?