# Magento 2 - "Property \"Slider\" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\\Eav\\Api\\Data\\AttributeOptionInterface\"."

Tags: magento2, attributes, api, interface

I am trying to override `Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface` in my custom module. I want to add one new option to existing interface.

The idea behind is, As of now we can only pass defined options data in attribute options **REST API**

**See below API request format for more clarity.**

**Api**

```
Url = http://test.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/attributes/manufacturer/options/
Api Methodd - Post
Api body - {
  "option": {
    "label": "test",
    "is_default": "true",
  }
}
```

**As of now its passing 3 parameters as value, I want to add my custom 4th parameters Ex - Slider.**

So parameters should be

```
{
  "option": {
    "label": "test",
    "is_default": "true",
    "slider":"test1"
  }
}
```

**I have tried to override interface and its method but its giving property setter not defined**

**Error Message**

```
"message": "Property \"Slider\" does not have corresponding setter in class \"Magento\\Eav\\Api\\Data\\AttributeOptionInterface\"."
```

So here my question is how can I override API interface and pass my custom or add my option in existing parameters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To resolve this issue, We require to override mainly two interfaces and model. After overriding interfaces and model, Overrided interfaces requires binding with model using **di.xml** to initiate objects while API call.

Check the below code to add new fields to **AttributeOptionInterface**.

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">  
    <preference for="Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Option" type="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Model\Eav\Entity\Attribute\Option" />  
    <preference for="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Api\Eav\Data\AttributeOptionInterface" type="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Model\Eav\Entity\Attribute\Option" />
    <preference for="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Api\Catalog\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\OptionManagement" />
</config>
```

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Api\Eav\Data\AttributeOptionInterface.php**

```
<?php 

namespace [Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Api\Eav\Data;

interface AttributeOptionInterface extends \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterface
{
    /**
     * Get slider
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSlider();

    /**
     * Set slider
     *
     * @param string $slider
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSlider($slider);
}
```

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Model\Eav\Entity\Attribute\Option.php**

```
<?php 

namespace [Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Model\Eav\Entity\Attribute;

class Option extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Option implements \Ktpl\SliderEavOptions\Api\Eav\Data\AttributeOptionInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSlider()
    {
        return $this->getData('slider');
    }

    /**
     * Set slider value
     *
     * @param string $slider
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSlider($slider)
    {
        return $this->setData('slider', $slider);
    }
}
```

After overriding interface to add  'slider' field and overring **option.php**, it is required to change the parameter type of API call for attribute options in **webapi.xml** for **Magento_Catalog** module.

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\etc\webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/products/attributes/:attributeCode/options" method="GET">
        <service class="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Api\Catalog\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface" method="getItems"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::attributes_attributes" />
        </resources>
    </route>    
    <route url="/V1/products/attributes/:attributeCode/options" method="POST">
        <service class="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Api\Catalog\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface" method="add" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::attributes_attributes" />
        </resources>
    </route>    
    <route url="/V1/products/attributes/:attributeCode/options/:optionId" method="DELETE">
        <service class="[Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Api\Catalog\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface" method="delete" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::attributes_attributes" />
        </resources>
    </route>        
</routes>
```

And Finally,

**[Package_Name][Module_Name]\Api\Catalog\ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface.php**

```
<?php

namespace [Package_Name]\[Module_Name]\Api\Catalog;

/**
 * @api
 */
interface ProductAttributeOptionManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve list of attribute options
     *
     * @param string $attributeCode
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @return \Ktpl\SliderEavOptions\Api\Eav\Data\AttributeOptionInterface[]
     */
    public function getItems($attributeCode);

    /**
     * Add option to attribute
     *
     * @param string $attributeCode
     * @param \Ktpl\SliderEavOptions\Api\Eav\Data\AttributeOptionInterface $option
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @return bool
     */
    public function add($attributeCode, $option);

    /**
     * Delete option from attribute
     *
     * @param string $attributeCode
     * @param string $optionId
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete($attributeCode, $optionId);
}
```

Comment: @Hitarth Pattani - Very well explained , yes its working . Thanks

Comment: @Hitarth Pattani - Great Answer.